# Will $E[E[X|F]|G] = E[X|G]$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, expectation

Let $F$ and $G$ be two sigma algebras where $F$ is contained in $G$. Normally we will have the following:

$E[E[X|G]|F] = E[X|F]$, so I wonder if $E[E[X|F]|G] = E[X|G]$.

I am asking the above question because I have the following :

$E[X|F]*E[X|G]$, since $F$ is contained in G, and $E[X|F]$ is $F$ measurable, then $E[X|F]$ is $G$ measurable , so $E[X|F]*E[X|G] = E[E[X|F]*X|G]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not. Try $F=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ and $G=\sigma(X)$, then $E(X\mid F)=E(X)$ hence $E(E(X\mid F)\mid G)=E(X)$ while $E(X\mid G)=X$.

Comment: I already made this suggestion, although not as explicitly: you could grab a textbook on the subject and learn the basics from it.

Comment: Thank you again, you save me many times today. Can you suggest a good one ? I am kind of jumping into study these stuff right away. I am sitting in a Stochastic Differential Eq class right now. I am an applied math major with the intention to do numerical work. And my advisor told me to take this one so that it can help me for modeling stochastic event.Thus I am not good at this kind of stuff, and the professor for the SDE course rushes through the theory part.

Comment: David Williams, *Probability with martingales*.